# get data with recvfrom

Tags: c++, c, networking

I want to retrieve data from socket with `recvfrom()`

The `recvfrom()` allow to get a buffer which contains IP header, TCP header and the Data.

are there a quick function to point directly to the data?
Should we convert the data to host (network to host) in order to read the data?

I do not want to use `read()` since `read()` do not give the ip header and tcp header

I think it should be something like this:

```
recvfrom(sock, packet, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0, NULL, NULL);
iph = (struct iphdr*)packet;
iphlen = iph->ihl* 4;
tcph = (struct tcphdr*)(packet + iphlen);
tcphlen = tcph->doff * 4;

data = packet + iphlen + tcphlen;
```

But I do not know if Have to convert the data to host (network to host) ?

Comment: An answer requires an example.

Comment: char *data = buf + sizeof(ip_hdr) + sizeof(tcp_hdr). No need to convert the data.

Comment: @sergeyrar the size of tcp header is variable. ANd could be retrieved from HLEN field  of the TCP header

Comment: `recvfrom()` does not get a buffer with all the headers. Just the data. It would make no sense to have headers in a TCP stream.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a `SOCK_RAW` socket is used.

The IP header length is located in the 4 lower bits of first byte of the IP header, and counts 32-bit integers.
The TCP header length is located in the 4 upper bits of 13th byte of the TCP header, and counts 32-bit integers.

According to `/usr/include/netinet/ip.h` and `/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h`, the `iph->ihl` and `tcph->doff` bit-fields already consider endianness and since they are less than a byte long (4 bits) they are not subject to any further hton/ntoh conversion.